# fullcalendar not getting events from google calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

fullcalendar is not retrieving the events from google calendar, i read something that google calendar api does not support fullcalendar anymore?.i don't know if its true.

here is my code

```
$(function () {
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
buttonText: {
  today: 'today',
  month: 'month',
  week: 'week',
  day: 'day'
},
googleCalendarApiKey: 'myApi',
eventSources: {
  googleCalendarId: 'example@gmail.com'
  }
 })
});
```

**UPDATE**

make it work by using this code

```
 eventSources: [
   { googleCalendarApiKey: 'your api key',
   googleCalendarId: 'email@gmail.com',
   className: 'fc-event-email'}];
```

Comment: From Nov 17th 2014, google shutdown V1 and V2 of their calendar API's.For full calendar to work with Google calendar upgrade to the latest version of FullCalendar or at least replace gcal.js with this file https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/v1.x/gcal.js . In the above code, you have to include  googleCalendarApiKey and googleCalendarId inside eventSources. check this link http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/google_calendar/ for documentation

Comment: i make it work by putting apikey inside eventsource ` eventSources: [
      { googleCalendarApiKey: 'your api key',
       googleCalendarId: 'email@gmail.com',
       className: 'fc-event-email'},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Nov 17th 2014, google shutdown V1 and V2 of their calendar API's.For full calendar to work with Google calendar upgrade to the latest version of FullCalendar or at least replace gcal.js with this file github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/v1.x/gcal.js . In the above code, you have to include googleCalendarApiKey and googleCalendarId inside eventSources. check this link fullcalendar.io/docs1/google_calendar for documentation

Comment: i am having an issue with events, its fine to show the events from google calendar but the problem is its not showing the events for the **next month and previous month**.       
any help .?